# Как реактивно получать обновление данных из БД SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, androidx

Использую надстройку Room. У меня есть некоторая сущность

```
@Entity
data class MedicalData(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Text") val text: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Number") val number: Int?
)
```

DAO для нее

```
@Dao
interface MedicalDataDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MedicalData")
    fun getAll(): List<MedicalData>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MedicalData  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :limit")
    fun getList(limit: Int): List<MedicalData>

    @Insert
    fun add(vararg medicalData: MedicalData)

    @Delete
    fun clear(medicalData: MedicalData)
}
```

И сама БД

```
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun medicalDataDao(): MedicalDataDao
}
```

Создаю экземпляр БД и добавляю в него некоторые объекты:

```
bservable.create<MedicalData> {
            val db = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "medtor").build()
            val medicalDataDao = db.medicalDataDao()
            val testObject = MedicalData(0, "some", 123)
            val testObject2 = MedicalData(1, "test", 456)
            val testObject3 = MedicalData(2, "text", 789)
            medicalDataDao.add(testObject)
            medicalDataDao.add(testObject2)
            medicalDataDao.add(testObject3)
        }.subscribeOn(
            Schedulers.io()
        ).subscribeBy(
            onNext = { print("onNext: $it") },
            onError = { print("onError: $it") },
            onComplete = { print("Complete") }
        )
```

Как я могу реактивно получать список объектов при добавлении нового, чтобы при вызове medicalDataDao.add(object) вызывался метод getAll() и выводил данные хотя бы в консоль?

Comment: Вам нужно помещать результаты запросов к БД в LiveData (в DAO), затем подписаться на наблюдение через метод observe(). Теперь при изменениях в БД у вас будет срабатывать обсервер, там уже можете делать, что вам надо. Для начала https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/525-urok-2-livedata.html

Comment: Если данные отображаются в RecyclerView, то есть такой ListAdapter, через его метод submitList() список будет обновлятся автоматически при изменении данных в БД. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter?hl=id

Comment: нужно использовать нечто кроме LiveData ввиду архитектуры приложения

Comment: RxJava тогда можно, там тоже есть обсервер